# Can I read B.csv and write to A.csv in new columns without read A.csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask

A(csv file) record stock price which crawl from a stock-website everyday.

```
Stock_num     Stock_name       20201201
0001           appl             201.3
0002           goog            1001.5
```

B(csv file) newest data crawl from same stock-website

```
Stock_num     Stock_name       20201202
0001           appl               208.3 
0002           goog               999.8
```

I want to use pandas to write B into A in below format(without read A).

```
Stock_num     Stock_name       20201201    20201202
0001           appl             201.3         208.3 
0002           goog            1001.5         999.8
```

I had try below:
`B.to_csv('A.csv',index=False,mode='a', encoding='utf_8_sig')`

But what I got is:

```
Stock_num     Stock_name       20201201
0001           appl               201.3
0002           goog              1001.5
Stock_num     Stock_name       20201202
0001           appl               208.3 
0002           goog               999.8
```

I know I can read A.csv and concat with b.csv then output.
But is there a way I can write B.csv into A.csv ***without read A.csv?***

Comment: Use `A = A.merge(B)`.

Comment: In this way, shouldn't I read A.csv into pandas first?

Comment: Yes, use `A = pd.read_csv('A.csv')`  and `B = pd.read_csv('B.csv')`. Then, `A = A.merge(B)`.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I don't think that is his question. For example, what if the A file is 10GB and the B file is 10GB and the user only has 16GB on his computer. Reading between the lines, I think he is trying to append to an existing file, so that he doesn't have to read it in. If memory is the issue, I would recommend using `dask`. You can not append with `to_csv` like you can with `to_sql` or something. Also, you can only append row-wise with `to_sql`. You might want to try out the `csv` module rather than using pandas, but I am not sure as that could just create other problems.

Comment: @David Erickson Ok I will try use CSV module  first. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DavidErickson Reopened the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if `dask` helps it run faster. You are still reading in both files, but it could be hundreds of times faster/more memory efficient with `dask`:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
A = dd.read_csv('Desktop/A.csv')
B = dd.read_csv('Desktop/B.csv')
df = A.merge(B)
df = df.compute()
df.to_csv('C.csv', index=False)
```